# how to resample fft after changing fftfreq

Tags: python, python-3.x, fft

I want to change the frequencies of a wav music file, and I am using scipy.fftpack.
May I ask how can I resample X after manipulating freq?

```
X = fftpack.fft(music)
freq = fftpack.fftfreq(len(X)) * sample_rate
freq = freq * 2 //for example
...//how to update X according to this new freq?
output = fftpack.rfft(X)
```

I have searched a lot of documents and couldn't find such examples.